# C# Pass a delegate as an argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, events, arguments

I am aware I can do this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += delegate(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //handle event
};
client.UploadStringAsync(myURI, "POST", "some_data");
```

But is there a way I can pass an inline delegate as an argument? Something like this:

```
DoRequest("some_data",
    delegate(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //handle event
    });

public void DoRequest(string data, UploadStringCompletedEventHandler event)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadStringCompleted += event;
    client.UploadStringAsync(myURI, "POST", data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write exactly that except that `event` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Before, I was wrapping an event cast around one of my lines which messed things up. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that code is correct, except you can't call your parameter event.  I'd also use a lambda expression instead because it's nicer.

DoRequest("some_data", (o, e) => {/* handle event */});